# How two identical domains work on Internet when they got signed from two different CA

Tags: certificates, http, dns

Let's say A and B.
Considering A and B are from same location.
A went to the verisign and get signed for example.com
B went to the godaddy.com and get signed for same domain(example.com)

Now question is how they are going to resolve for dns names and how this works on internet?

## No local host files need to be configured

Comment: Certificates have zero bearing on how a domain resolves. That is the purpose of the domain. So you can get multiple certificates but it is pointless if not a waste of money since only one could be used. Unless you were to say bind this cert to this port and this one to that one. Some companies do that when they have a public facing domain with a trusted CA and then an application with a custom CA under their control but chose to use the domain for both. But it doesn't make sense to use two completely different trusted CAs. Especially when the expected endpoint is the same.

Comment: Absolutely, when we carry this Ina different scenario if they are from two different places and end point is different (two different webservers). Will this create conflict?

Comment: You do not seem to understand how DNS works. Domain lookup is u related to certificates

Answer (score 2):

This situation would not be possible in the first place. The certificate authority must verify that the person requesting a certificate for `example.com` actually owns `example.com` before issuing a certificate. If A is the owner of `example.com`, then B obviously isn't, assuming they are independent entities.

Comment: Does that mean there will be a centralized system to check whether domain exists or not? Will verisign and godaddy will sync their signed certificates or how that works?

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaKanduri Yes, in this case it would be the nameservers of the `.com` TLD. When you register a domain, your registrar will check with this server to ensure the domain isn't already registered. Two people cannot end up owning the same domain name even if you go through different registrars. If you don't own a domain name, you can't get a certificate for it.

Comment: At an unconditional scenario, what happens if they register at the same time?

Comment: You may wish to read about the difference between the [registry and registrar](https://whois.icann.org/en/domain-name-registration-process) (this [serverfault post](http://serverfault.com/questions/161720/can-you-have-multiple-dns-registrars) may help too). One of the registrations will be "first" and the other transaction will fail, since changes are made to a single registry.

Comment: @tlng05 How I understood this question is that in this case they are the same person but they are purchasing a certificate from two different CAs for the same domain. So if this is the case both issuers would see this person as the owner.